# How to remove Virus Ransomware and recover file .verasto ? Please HELP this is my life

Tags: data-recovery, virus-removal

My pc just got into a big problem all the file are changed their type to .verasto. I don't know how to get it back please help me, guy. I'm begging you. Please

Comment: If they files are encrypted the only way other than decryption is a restore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 1):

Before answering any of this, this question should belong to https://security.stackexchange.com

You have been visited by a ransomware known as STOP, to be specific, the DJVU variant <strike>(dejavu anyone)</strike>

STOP is a ransomware by some group known as "gorentos". In case of your DJVU variant, there are also other encrypted extensions like

```
djvuu, uudjvu, blower, tfudet, promok, djvut, djvur, klope, charcl, doples, luces,
luceq, chech, proden, drume, tronas, trosak, grovas, grovat, roland, refols, 
raldug, etols, guvara, browec, norvas, moresa, verasto, hrosas, kiratos, todarius, 
hofos, roldat, dutan, sarut, fedasot, forasom, berost, fordan, codnat, codnat1, 
bufas, dotmap, radman, ferosas, rectot, skymap, mogera, rezuc, stone, redmat, 
lanset, davda, poret, pidon, heroset, myskle, boston, muslat, gerosan, vesad, 
horon, neras, truke, dalle, lotep, nusar, litar, besub, cezor, lokas, godes, budak, 
vusad, herad, berosuce, gehad, gusau, madek, tocue, darus, lapoi, todar, dodoc, 
novasof, bopador, ntuseg, ndarod, access, format, nelasod, mogranos, nvetud, 
cosakos, kovasoh, lotej, prandel, zatrov, masok, brusaf, londec, kropun, londec

Source: https://howtofix.guide/about-djvu-stop-ransomware/?cn-reloaded=1
```

However, you can easily solve this by downloading a certain Decrypter by Micheal Gillespie. It's free, but the downside is that you gotta provide an encrypted version of the file and a decrypted version in order to let it figure out the decryption key. After you run the program as administrator from desktop, be sure to never visit `api.2ip.ua` or `morgem.ru` ever again.

It's not really that bad even if you do not have a file pair. DJVU STOP only encrypts an approximate 5 MB of a file, and the rest of it is still readable, so not all of your data is lost.

Edit:

There's actually no way that...

You get yourself in a situation where you don't have a pair!

Yep! You heard me right. According to https://howtofix.guide/about-djvu-stop-ransomware , the `_readme` file says:

```
You can send one of your encrypted file from your PC and we decrypt it for free.
But we can decrypt only 1 file for free. File must not contain valuable information.
```

A while later in the `_readme` file:

```
To get this software you need write on our e-mail:
gorentos@bitmessage.ch

Reserve e-mail address to contact us:
gorentos@firemail.cc

Our Telegram Account(note from Aaron:what is that?):
@datarestore

Your personal ID:(note from Aaron:this is your own ID, unique for you in the _readme file)
```

So, find that `_readme` file, get an encrypted file with no sensitive information, and email it to `gorentos@bitmessage.ch` or `gorentos@firemail.cc` with that personal ID!